# Facehugger in jar -- how would that happen?

Tags: aliens-1986

Facehuggers are generally found in one of three states;

1. In its egg
2. On a host's face
3. Dead

But the facehugger [in the vessel](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/stasis-tues.jpg) reacts to stimulus -- that is, it is not dead.

Is it explained how this facehugger was obtained?

Answer (score 6):

Bishop identifies that the facehugger in the specimen jar was *removed before it could implant its eggs*. This explains why it's still alive and mobile since it's still looking for a host.

> 

The [official novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens_(novel)) goes into a little more detail on how this specimen was collected.

> "Removed surgically before embryo implantation could be completed.
> Standard surgical procedures useless."
>
> "Wonder why?" Gorman was as interested in the specimen as the rest of
> them but not to the point of taking his eyes off the rest of the room.
>
> **"Body fluids dissolved the instruments as they were applied. They had
> to use surgical lasers to both remove and cauterize the specimen.** It
> was attached to somebody named Marachuk, John L." She glanced up at
> Burke, who shook his head.
>
> "Doesn’t ring a bell. Not an administrator or one of the higher-ups.
> Must’ve been a tractor driver or roustabout."
>
> She looked back down at the report. "He died during the procedure.
> They killed him getting it off."
>
> <sub><sup>[Aliens: Official Novelisation](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Aliens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: I just watched the "special version" which showed Newt's family. Is this explanation of the free-living and still dangerous facehugger originating because of fatal surgical removal shown in orginal theatrical release because I do not recall this at all.

Comment: @releseabe - Rebecca "Newt" Jorden's parents were attacked in a different incident -  https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/John_Marachuk

Comment: I mention her family as a way of distinguishing versions. My question is whether the explanation about pre-implantation removal is present in both the "Newt's parents" version and the version we saw in 1986.

Answer (score 5):

The facehugger was removed surgically *prior* to implanting its eggs.

> **Bishop**: "Surgically removed before embryo implantation. Subject: Marachek, John J. died during the procedure." They killed him taking it off.
>
> <sub><sup>Aliens Transcript</sup></sub>